# Standalone .NET CLR Debugger for .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, debugging, com

I have a COM application which is effectively an add-in for PowerPoint. In previous versions, it utilized .NET 2.0 and later, .NET 3.5 (which both have the same CLR version). I used to WinDbg and CDB for debugging my .NET applications, purely for exceptions. It works nicely... However, it does not work now that I have used .NET framework for my latest version!

Does anyone know of a fairly straight-forward and lightweight .NET 4.0 debugger, which would be similar to WinDbg? I understand Microsoft no longer support CLR debugging for .NET 4.0, but why???

Additionally, would anyone know of any other 'light-weight' method I can use to debug my application? It is installed on hundreds of machines and installing VS2010 is not an option unfortunately!

Appreciate any input.

Mike

Comment: `understand Microsoft no longer support CLR debugging for .NET 4.0, but why???` That is not true. CLR debugging with SOS / PSSCOR works fine for v4.

Comment: @vcsjones is this standalone and able to run from a USB, just like WinDbg?

Comment: Why is Visual Studio not an option?

Comment: @Ramhound the app is installed on hundreds of client machines, and when I try to troubleshoot issues wherre I'd say a .NET debug could be useful on their machines, installing Visual Studio is no exactly ideal.

Comment: @DerekP I'm saying that WinDbg does work with v4. You just need to load the sos.dll debugging extension, which is included in the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by WinDbg not able to debug .NET 4 as that is definitely supported. SOS, PSSCOR, and SOSEX all work with .NET 4.

However, keep in mind that the .NET runtime DLL was renamed in .NET 4 from mscorwks to clr, so when you load SOS you have to do `.loadby sos clr` instead of `.loadby sos mscorwks`.

Comment: And use the v4.0.30319 version of sos.dll.  It already knows about clr.dll

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, you need to use the version of SOS that comes with the framework. The `.loadby` command just picks up the extension from the same location as the runtime. If the framework location is part of the path, `.load` works fine as well.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I'm still having trouble debugging .NET 4.0. I know I am producing an exception. My script looks like this: `"%~dp0cdb.exe" -pn EXCEL.exe -c ".loadby sos clr;sxi *;sxi av;sxe -c \"!clrstack;!pe;.echotime;.echo ***;g;\" clr;g;" > "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\4MQ_log.txt"` Any ideas why this would not work? I can get the log to create, but it's not recognizing any of the eceptions, which I am deliberately creating!

Comment: @DerekP Looks fine to me. Are you sure your code runs in the Excel.exe process?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Yeah 100% the .NET app is an Excel add-in, so it cannot run against any other process. Really frustrating as it in debugging .NET 2.0 and 3.5, but not 4.0!

Comment: I'm wondering if this is to do with my CDB version being so old (2009). The version I am using is 6.9.0003.113